# The object is transparent, when imported from FBX file

Tags: transparency

My downloaded object is transparent. How to fix it?

[The file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/wo2vhrx8qdlklhk/riggid_f.blend/file)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCzzD.png

Comment: Hello, I'm voting to close this question because as it stands it's impossible to answer on its own. Please add screens of your interface.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 1):

In the *Material* panel, under *Settings*, choose *Blend Mode > Opaque*:

[image]